# Can I use parallel python 2.7 and python 3.7 in the same Intellij project directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, intellij-idea

I use in my Intellij (Ultimate 2019.1) project python 2.7 and 3.7 in the same directory.

If I set projectdir > File > Project structure > Project Settings > Facets > Python > Python Interpreter > Python 2.7

My python 2.7 files show syntax OK but python 3.7 are wrong.

If I change the Interpreter to Python 3.7 my python 3.7 are fine the 2.7 not?

Comment: python3 and python2 have slightly differences in sintax and behaviour. You would need to adapt your code so it runs in both versions. BTW, python 2 is in its last year of life...

Comment: The 2.7 code is from mapnik 4.0. I can't change it.

Comment: You can not use a library that is not supported by the version.

Comment: It's only possible define interpreter version on directory level not on file level - correct?

Comment: if the code is not shared yes... but **whatever** that use that lib cannot be run in python3

Comment: write this as answer an I accept this.

Comment: Hope I helped, sadly it is like that. But as I said, I think you should move to python3 versions asap :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python code cannot be mixed. All libraries and code should support the version you are working with. If some is not compatible with that version you **can not** use that code.

Always use libraries that are compatible with the python version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using modules. You'd need to separate the Python 2 and 3 code out (e.g. into two parallel folders). Then you'd configure two different modules, setting the SDK for one to Python 2 and the SDK for the other to Python 3. If you want to get really carried away you could do this multiple times, creating many modules, and then grouping these into Python 2 modules and Python 3 modules.

See: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configure-modules.html

And: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html